# "Invalid Date" in React Native on real device only

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

In my React Native app I am displaying the following in a `Text` string:

`moment(new Date('2019-02-02 7:00:00')).format('h:mm A')`

This works fine in an emulator, but returns "Invalid Date" on a real iOS device.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could resolve it?

Comment: the A flag isn't supported on iOS.

Comment: Perfect, thanks to both ^^

Comment: Also, you don't need to create a new date to create a new moment Object, you can simply pass your date string, and maybe a format, just to be sure.

Comment: @Nicolas is there any difference between `moment(new Date(...))` and `moment(...)`?

Comment: In the first case, you have one more step, your code is creating a date object, then creates a momentjs object. It's not the end of the world but if you would do that a billion times, you could encounter some performance issues.